# Returning different types from a function

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a function I wrote that checks if the string given to it is true, false, or something else. If it's True, I want it to return the boolean true, if it's false, I want to return the boolean false, and if it's anything else, I want it to keep returning the string.

```
Public Function ConvertToBoolean(InputString As String) As Variant
Dim TempResults As Variant


    If InputString = "True" Then
        TempResults = True
    ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
        TempResults = False
    Else
        TempResults = InputString
    End If

    ConvertToBoolean = TempResults


End Function
```

However, it keeps defaulting to strings. I could dim it as boolean, but then regular strings get returned as TRUE, instead of as a string.

How can I force/make the function type conversion work? Probably need it inside of the if statement, but I have no idea how to do that.

Can't dim inside of the if (Although perhaps I could re-dim? Going to check)

Edit: Further testing is showing that most of the time, a boolean is returned - but once in awhile it's returning a string instead, with all of the associated problems that I was trying to fix in the first place. So my question remains the same:

**How can I explicitly declare a function (Or a variable) to return one given type or another?**

Edit 2: Since people don't seem to believe that code doesn't always work perfect or the same every time:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194565/discussion-on-question-by-selkie-returning-different-types-from-a-function).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So many thanks to @MathieuGuindon for explaining to me exactly how variants worked, and pointed me on the right path.

With that, my code is now:

```
Option Compare Text
Public Function ConvertToBoolean(InputString As String) As Variant
Dim IsBoolean As Boolean
Dim ReturnString As String
Dim ReturnBoolean As Boolean


If InputString = "True" Then
    IsBoolean = True
    ReturnBoolean = True
ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
    IsBoolean = True
    ReturnBoolean = False
Else
    IsBoolean = False
    ReturnString = InputString
End If

If IsBoolean Then
    ConvertToBoolean = ReturnBoolean
Else
    ConvertToBoolean = ReturnString
End If


End Function
```

Of course, as @MathieuGuindon mentioned, if you want to make this code ACTUALLY WORK, (as opposed to being a "force the type" exercise), you'll want to add StrComp() (Preferable), or Option Compare Text (Less preferable, apparently buggy)

Comment: This modified version (and the original too) will work _if and only if_ you include `Option Compare Text`.  I know you said you had that line, but the only way I can reproduce your issue is to omit it (same for both versions of your code)

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Yes, that makes the code work the way it's supposed to, but has little to nothing to do with the question I was asking

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
Public Function ConvertToBoolean(InputString As String) As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim ret
    s = Trim$(UCase$(InputString))
    Select Case s
        Case "TRUE", "FALSE"
            ret = CBool(s)
        Case Else
            ret = InputString
    End Select
    ConvertToBoolean = ret
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Since this Q is very much about Variant and implicit type conversions, it's worth noting that both `Trim` and `UCase` take and return a `Variant`, while `Trim$` and `UCase$` both take and return a `String`. I'd have gone with `StrComp` instead of uppercasing the input, but this code has no reason to blow up or otherwise fail, save for a type mismatch if the input cell actually contains a worksheet `Error` value, which can't be coerced into a `String` - but Excel will handle that, I think. Very elegant, upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of future readers:

The root issue was case sensitivity, solved by ensuring compares are by `Text` and not `Binary`

Here's the evidence

[image]

Note that Boolean values display UPPER CASE, center aligned.  String values in orignal case, left aligned, numbers right aligned.

Here's a version, optimised to handle Errors, numbers, and self contained for Text based tests (this was *not* the version used in the tests below, as it contains additional features)

```
Public Function ConvertToBoolean(Val As Variant) As Variant
    If IsError(Val) Then
        ConvertToBoolean = Val
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Val) Then
        ConvertToBoolean = vbNullString
    ElseIf StrComp(Trim$(Val), "True", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ConvertToBoolean = True
    ElseIf StrComp(Trim$(Val), "False", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ConvertToBoolean = False
    Else
        ConvertToBoolean = Val
    End If
End Function
```

---

<sub>Tests were based on this code</sub>

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Function ConvertToBoolean1a(InputString As String) As Variant
    Dim TempResults As Variant

    If InputString = "True" Then
        TempResults = True
    ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
        TempResults = False
    Else
        TempResults = InputString
    End If

    ConvertToBoolean1a = TempResults
End Function

Public Function ConvertToBoolean2a(InputString As String) As Variant
    Dim IsBoolean As Boolean
    Dim ReturnString As String
    Dim ReturnBoolean As Boolean

    If InputString = "True" Then
        IsBoolean = True
        ReturnBoolean = True
    ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
        IsBoolean = True
        ReturnBoolean = False
    Else
        IsBoolean = False
        ReturnString = InputString
    End If

    If IsBoolean Then
        ConvertToBoolean2a = ReturnBoolean
    Else
        ConvertToBoolean2a = ReturnString
    End If
End Function
```

<sub>And in a separate module (I've modified Davids version slightly to give a fair comparison.  His original version handles leading/trailing spaces, but thats an additional feature and costs time)</sub>

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConvertToBoolean1b(InputString As String) As Variant
    Dim TempResults As Variant

    If InputString = "True" Then
        TempResults = True
    ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
        TempResults = False
    Else
        TempResults = InputString
    End If

    ConvertToBoolean1b = TempResults
End Function

Public Function ConvertToBoolean2b(InputString As String) As Variant
    Dim IsBoolean As Boolean
    Dim ReturnString As String
    Dim ReturnBoolean As Boolean

    If InputString = "True" Then
        IsBoolean = True
        ReturnBoolean = True
    ElseIf InputString = "False" Then
        IsBoolean = True
        ReturnBoolean = False
    Else
        IsBoolean = False
        ReturnString = InputString
    End If

    If IsBoolean Then
        ConvertToBoolean2b = ReturnBoolean
    Else
        ConvertToBoolean2b = ReturnString
    End If
End Function

Public Function ConvertToBoolean3(Val As String) As Variant
    If StrComp(Val, "True", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ConvertToBoolean3 = True
    ElseIf StrComp(Val, "False", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ConvertToBoolean3 = False
    Else
        ConvertToBoolean3 = Val
    End If
End Function


Public Function ConvertToBoolean4(Val As Variant) As Variant
    Dim s As String
    s = UCase$(Val)
    Select Case s
        Case "TRUE", "FALSE"
            ConvertToBoolean4 = CBool(s)
        Case Else
            ConvertToBoolean4 = Val
    End Select
End Function
```

<sub>I've also run a speed test to compare performance, using this code</sub>

```
Sub Test()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim T1 As Single, T2 As Single, T3 As Single, T4 As Single
    Dim res As Variant

    Dim Dat2(1 To 5) As String
    Dat2(1) = "true"
    Dat2(2) = "false"
    Dat2(3) = "   true"
    Dat2(4) = "zx"
    Dat2(5) = ""
    Dim cl As Range

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    n = 1000000

    T1 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To 5
            res = ConvertToBoolean1a(Dat2(j))
        Next
    Next
    T2 = Timer()

    T3 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To 5
            res = ConvertToBoolean2a(Dat2(j))
        Next
    Next
    T4 = Timer()

    'Verion 1a OP 1
    [F22] = (T2 - T1) / n * 1000000#
    'Verion 2a OP 2
    [H22] = (T4 - T3) / n * 1000000#


    n = n / 100

    Set cl = [f10:f15]
    T1 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        cl.Calculate
    Next
    T2 = Timer()

    Set cl = [h10:h15]
    T3 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        cl.Calculate
    Next
    T4 = Timer()

    'Verion 1a OP 1 UDF
    [F23] = (T2 - T1) / n * 1000000#
    'Verion 2a OP 1 UDF
    [H23] = (T4 - T3) / n * 1000000#

End Sub
```

<sub>And</sub>

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim T1 As Single, T2 As Single, T3 As Single, T4 As Single
    Dim res As Variant

    Dim Dat2(1 To 5) As String
    Dat2(1) = "true"
    Dat2(2) = "false"
    Dat2(3) = "   true"
    Dat2(4) = "zx"
    Dat2(5) = ""
    Dim cl As Range

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    n = 1000000
    T1 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To 5
            res = ConvertToBoolean3(Dat2(j))
        Next
    Next
    T2 = Timer()

    T3 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To 5
            res = ConvertToBoolean4(Dat2(j))
        Next
    Next
    T4 = Timer()

    'Verion 3 mine
    [J22] = (T2 - T1) / n * 1000000#
    'Verion 4 david
    [K22] = (T4 - T3) / n * 1000000#


    n = n / 100
    Set cl = [j10:j15]
    T1 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        cl.Calculate
    Next
    T2 = Timer()

    Set cl = [K10:K15]
    T3 = Timer()
    For i = 1 To n
        cl.Calculate
    Next
    T4 = Timer()

    'Verion 3 mine  UDF
    [J23] = (T2 - T1) / n * 1000000#
    'Verion 4 david UDF
    [K23] = (T4 - T3) / n * 1000000#


End Sub
```